# Convert an array of UInt8 into a String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, uint8array

I have an array of `UInt8` characters that I want to be combined into one cohesive `String`. I know `String` has the `.utf8` property, and running a for loop over those characters was how I made the `UInt8` array, but now I need the reverse of this.

For example, the `UInt8` array:

```
[83, 87, 73, 70, 84]
```

and the desired end result:

```
"SWIFT"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use String [bytes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(bytes:encoding:)) initializer:

```
init?<S>(
    bytes: S,
    encoding: String.Encoding
) where S : Sequence, S.Element == UInt8
```

> Initializer
> **init(bytes:encoding:)**
>
> Creates a new string equivalent to the given bytes interpreted in >the specified encoding.

```
String(bytes: [83, 87, 73, 70, 84], encoding: .utf8) // "SWIFT"
```